# scrollable area while overflow is hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, overflow, hidden

Same question as [A scrollable area with the overflow hidden but no scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763408/a-scrollable-area-with-the-overflow-hidden-but-no-scroll-bar).

That question was never answered though.
They gave up because it is maybe a bad idea for UI.

I agree but my client is adamant about no scroll bars being part of the site. All scrollable areas scroll automatically when mouse hovers near the edge. Otherwise scrolling occurs with touch screen or scroll ball/trackpad.

Is it possible to style away scroll bars with javascript if not css?

Comment: do you know how to implement?

Comment: check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-to-disable-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-allow-scrolling-with-wheel-or-a

Answer (score 1):

While, as you already said, it is a bad idea, you can use `overflow:hidden;` to hide your scrollbars and, as you mention, use `element.scrollTo(x,y)` when the mouse is near the edges of your scrollableElement/window, or in a mousewheel event, etc.

Comment: And what about people who navigate with the keyboard?

Comment: @steveax Well, my "etc" meant any other time you want to scroll use scrollTo... on keydown events as well. Though, if you're hiding the scrollbars from your page, you're obviously crippling the usability of your page, which I mentioned, is a bad idea to start with.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/amoqul/3/edit)*

I used the [mousewheel plugin by Brandon Aaron](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs)

Than i added some jQ:

```
var topPos = 0;
var scrH = $('#scrollable').outerHeight(true);
var parH = $('#parent').outerHeight(true);

$('#parent').mousewheel(function(event,delta){
    topPos = parseInt($('#scrollable').css('top'));
    if (delta > 0) {    // scrollUp
        if(topPos >= 0){ $('#scrollable').css({top: 0}); return; }
        $('#scrollable').css({top:'+=15px'}); 
    } else {            // scrollDown
        if(topPos <= (parH-scrH) ){ $('#scrollable').css({top: st}); return;}
        $('#scrollable').css({top:'-=15px'});
    }   
    $('#test').html(topPos+' '+scrH+' '+parH);  
});
```

... to this HTML:

```
<div id="parent">  
    <div id="scrollable">
        A very loooooong text.............
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:210px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:17px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#666;
}
#scrollable{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;        
    width:180px;
    padding:15px;
}
```

And here you go! Scrollable but no scrollbars!
(Ask if you have Q.) Happy coding!